# Having trouble saving a datetime in Rails 3 app that has mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to save the last date that a token is reset. I can't seem to get it to work.

1. I changed the field from a date attribute to datetime in a migration and used DateTime.now and that didn't work
2. I dropped the column and added it back, and that didn't work.
3. I added strftime formatting to match datetime format used in the database and that didn't work.
   I tried changing to Time.now and that didn't work... darn... just figured this out... attributes accessible. Nuts!

current code:

```
if current_user.token_date.nil?
  current_user.update_attributes(:token_date => Time.now)      
elsif Time.now - current_user.token_date > 1300000 #approx 15 days
  current_user.reset_authentication_token!
  current_user.update_attributes(:token_date => Time.now)
  flash[:notice] = "For your security we just..."
end
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

token_date has to be a DateTime attribute.

Then just add

```
current_user.update_attributes(:token_date => DateTime.now)
```

Comment: so in rails you can't have a Date field instead of DateTime? +1 from Martin (see gravatar)

Comment: this still isn't working even tho i did a migration to change token_date to a datetime field.

Comment: forgot to add to attr_accessible in the model.

Comment: You can have Date field if you want. DateTime is used to store Date and Time. So if you just need to store Date, you can use a Date field with current_user.update_attributes(:token_date => Date.today).

Comment: Yeah, I know. But for some reason Date.today was not storing. For now i'll just leave it datetime and come back to it later. Thanks for your help.